# UTC TO GMT Conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, gmt

I need to convert UTC/Local time to GMT+(?) format on requested timezone...
eg..

```
UTC to GMT 0
UTC to GMT+1
UTC to GMT-1
UTC to GMT+5
UTC to GMT-5
GMT+5 to GMT+4
GMT+5 to GMT-3
```

Comment: Natively, _JavaScript_ only supports producing _UTC_ and _local_ times from a _Date_. You can start from any timezone if you use _ISO 8601_ formatting, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTC is GMT for most practicable purposes. We (the English) invented it. Just add/subtract the hours.

Please visit Greenwich. Just outside london.

Comment: Whilst this is true, when you read the question OP really means a timezone designated by _GMT±X_

Comment: Also it was down to the invention of Trains (Steam locomotion) - Another English thing. Need for a timetable

Comment: Not all timezones are whole hours from GMT, e.g. IST (GMT+5:30)

Comment: That is true . The concept is the same

Answer (score 2):

```
var inputDateTime = "Thu Sep 24 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)";
var date = new Date(inputDateTime );
var GMTtime= ((date.getUTCMonth() + 1 ) + '/' + date.getUTCDate() + '/' + date.getUTCFullYear()+ ' ' + date.getUTCHours()+ ':' + date.getUTCMinutes()+ ':' + date.getUTCSeconds()+" GMT");
```